# Using TypeScript, how do I strongly type mysql query results

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and can't figure out if I'm strongly typing the results of my query correctly or not.  Here's the essence of my code...

```
import mysql2, {Pool} from "mysql2";
const pool: Pool = mysql2.createPool({...}).promise();

interface IUser {
    uid   : number;
    uname : string;
}

class UserController {

    public async getUser(id: number): Promise<IUser> {
        const [rows]: Array<{rows: IUser}> = await pool.query(
            "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?",["me@me.org"]);        
        return rows;
    }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler (3.3.1) complains about my `return rows` statement.

> TS2740: Type '{rows: IUser;}' is missing the following properties from
>   type 'IUser': uid and uname.

If I ignore the return with `// @ts-ignore` everything works great. I get my object back just fine without any errors.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

I made some changes, but I'm honestly confused as to why TypeScript doesn't complain.  It doesn't seem right at all.

```
    class UserController {

        public async getUser(id: number): Promise<{rows: IUser}> {
            const [rows]: Array<{rows: IUser}> = await pool.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 3");        
            return rows;
        }
    }
```

Is this right???

---

So, no that's all wrong.

When I thought about `query` returning `[rows, fields]` it started too make a little more sense. I think @joesph-climber is correct with some tweaked syntax.

This works and makes sense to me...

```
    class UserController {

        public async getUser(id: number): Promise<Array<{rows: IUser}>> {
            const [rows]: [Array<{rows: IUser}>] = await pool.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 3");        
            return rows;
        }
    }
```

This also works and is probably more readily understandable.

```
    class UserController {

        public async getUser(id: number): Promise<IUser[]> {
            const [rows]: [IUser[]] = await pool.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 3");        
            return rows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `{rows: IUser}` is not compatible with `IUser` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// the function should return a Promise that resolves to 
{ uid: number, uname: string }

// but typeof rows is 
{ rows: { uid: number, uname: string } }
```

Executing the example, the result I get is something like:

```
[ TextRow { uid: 1, uname: 'foo', email: 'foo@mail.com' } ]
```

So *pool.query* is returning an array with an array of IUser as first element.

> Returning multiple users:

```
class UserController {
    // returns all users
    public async getUsers(): Promise<Array<IUser>> {
        const [rows]: [Array<IUser>] = await pool.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `user`", []);
        return rows; // rows is Array<IUser> so it matches the promise type
    }
}
```

> Returning a specific user:

```
class UserController {
    public async getUser(id: number): Promise<IUser> { // Note the 
        const [rows]: [Array<IUser>] = 
            await pool.query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `email` = ?",
                            ["foo@mail.com"]);
        // If email is unique as it would be expected it will 
        // return a single value inside an array
        // rows is still Array<IUser>
        return rows[0]; // rows[0] is an IUser 
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the query to return multiple rows and can see that it's returning.... `[TextRow{},TextRow{},TextRow{}]`, which seems like an Array of TextRow objects, so maybe I'm not understanding what [Array<IUser>] means; when I look at that, I think An array with a single element that is an Array of IUser objects.

When I tried what you suggested, TypeScript complained about the function return type, `Promise<Array<ICwolDbUser>>` saying "Array<T> is forbidden for simple types.  use T[] instead".  And it complained about `return rows` "Type {rows: IUser}[] is not assignable to type IUser[]

Comment: if you want to tweak your answer from `Array<IUser>` to `IUser[]`, I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Both have the same meaning. But I agree that not using the same terms can be a little confusing. :-)

Comment: This does not work for me: `error TS2322: Type '[RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader, FieldPacket[]]' is not assignable to type '[IUser[]]'. Source has 2 element(s) but target allows only 1.`

Answer (score 22):

Using mysql2@1.7.0, typescript@3.6.3, @types/mysql2

The interface must extend RowDataPacket:

```
interface IUser extends RowDataPacket {
  ssid: string
}
```

From there you can pass in the type:

```
const [rows]: [IUser[], FieldPacket[]] = await connection.query<IUser[]>("SELECT ssid FROM user", [])
```

or simply

```
const [rows] = await connection.query<IUser[]>("SELECT ssid FROM user", [])
```

Comment: the problem with `RowDataPacket` is that it's too loose. see its d.t.s. the problem: once you extend the row interface - i. e. `IUser` in your example - any strict typing is gone so that you can do whatever with the returned row object... `row[0].whateverProperty` is fine and TS does not complain.

Comment: @dmudro but actually I don't think there is a better way :/

Comment: The 3rd package is `@types/msql`, there isn't a `@types/mysql2` npm package from what I'm seeing. Can't edit the answer as there are too many pending edits

Answer (score 6):

Think this works quite well

```
import {RowDataPacket} from 'mysql2'

const [rows]= await pool.query<IUser[] & RowDataPacket[][]>(
          "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's perfectly clear to me and this is easily the most concise solution to the problem that I've seen to far so well done!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error so I search in google and founded this example: https://github.com/types/mysql2/blob/master/test/promise.ts

so my code was like this

```
    const [user] = await pool.query<RowDataPacket[]>("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?", [email]);
        if(!user.length) {
            throw {
                error: true,
                message: 'no user founded'
            } 
        }
```

With this, I can use the autocomplete of vs code and have no errors

Comment: I get an error saying `Type 'Query' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` And there are red squiggly lines underneath the `[user]` ... :(

Answer (score 3):

Using `pool.query<type>` was not enough for me when trying to set variables that were going to be used later because the datatype `RowDataPacket` was still infringing on my types...

I ended up creating a wrapper for the `pool`'s `query` function. Looks like this:

```
type Row = import("mysql2").RowDataPacket
type Ok = import("mysql2").OkPacket
type dbDefaults = Row[] | Row[][] | Ok[] | Ok
type dbQuery<T> = T & dbDefaults

export const db = {
  query: async <T>(query: string, params?: Array<any>): Promise<[T, any]> => {
    return pool.promise().query<dbQuery<T>>(query, params)
  },
}
```

This allows me to use the `query` function in other parts of the project similar to other answers as

```
let result = await db.query<desiredType>("SELECT", [optionalArgs])
```

but it strips away the type information for RowDataPacket, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Building uponon @soohoKang's answer above, I do something like the following, which lets mysql2.query work (i.e. permissive RowDataPacket) but anything calling FooRepository.list() will get the strongly typed results:

```
import { Pool, RowDataPacket } from "mysql2/promise";
import { IFoo } from "./foo";

export class FooRepository {
    public constructor(private readonly pool: Pool) {}

    public async list() {
        const [results] = await this.pool.query<IFoo[] & RowDataPacket[]>
            ("SELECT id, name, etc FROM foo");
        return results as IFoo[];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach in the accepted answer didn't work for me (`typescript@3.5.2`, `mysql2@1.6.5`). This code

```js
interface IUserRow {
  ssid: string
}

const [rows]: [IUserRow[]] = await pool.query(
  'select ssid from user where id = ?',
  [session.userId],
)
```

gives me

```js
error TS2322: Type '[RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[], FieldPacket[]]' is not assignable to type '[IUserRow[]]'.
  Types of property '0' are incompatible.
    Type 'RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[]' is not assignable to type 'IUserRow[]'.
      Type 'RowDataPacket[]' is not assignable to type 'IUserRow[]'.
        Property 'ssid' is missing in type 'RowDataPacket' but required in type 'IUserRow'.
```

with `[rows]` highlighted.

I was able to get everything working with:

```js
interface IUserRow {
  ssid: string
}

const [rows] = await pool.query(
  'select ssid from user where id = ?',
  [session.userId],
)

// This first if statement is a type guard against rows possibly being OkPacket
if (Array.isArray(rows) && rows.length > 0) {
  // The casting works fine here
  const userRow = rows[0] as IUserRow
  if (userRow.ssid !== session.ssid) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I am no Typescript expert so there is probably a much better way to do this! Still, I hope I can potentially save someone frustration if they also have problems with the accepted answer.

Comment: Try `const [rows] = await pool.query<IUserRow[]>(`

Answer (score 0):

For those who read this post, are using *mysql2* with *typescript* and are still struggling like I were. I propose you to switch on *knex*, which is a great query builder and integrates very well *mysql2* on client and has good types for TS supports.

Starting the pool connection:

```
// database.ts
import Knex from "knex";
import { DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER } from "./env.js";

const knex = Knex({
  client: "mysql2",
  connection: {
    host: DB_HOST,
    user: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DB_NAME,
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 7,
  },
});

export { knex };
```

Starting querying:

```
import { knex } from "./database.js";

async function getArticles(...) {
   try {
    const articles = await knex<Article>("article").select();
    //     ^-- Article[]

    // response
   } catch (err) {
     // handle error
   }
}
```