# Strongly typing results from mysql2 in Typescript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, next.js

I am working on an application using NextJS and Typescript and am attempting to determine the best way to properly type my MySQL responses. Here is the API endpoint:

```js
import { hash } from "bcrypt";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import randomstring from "randomstring";

import { executeQuery } from "../../../lib/db";

const Test = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  // Manage password generation
  const password = randomstring.generate(16);
  const hashedPassword = hash(password, 10);

  // Create new auth using email and password
  const auth = await executeQuery(
    "INSERT INTO auth (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)",
    ["test@test.com", (await hashedPassword).toString()]
  );

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json(auth.insertId);
};

export default Test;
```

I am wanting to strongly type `insertId` to remove all warnings and errors through ESLint, but unfortunately, every effort I have made has been unsuccessful. The error I am getting is:

```
Property 'insertId' does not exist on type 'RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader | { error: unknown; }'.
  Property 'insertId' does not exist on type 'RowDataPacket[]'.ts(2339)
```

My `executeQuery` function is defined as:

```js
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

export const executeQuery = async (query: string, params: unknown[] = []) => {
  try {
    const db = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    });

    const [results] = await db.execute(query, params);
    db.end();

    return results;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
};
```

One of my implementation attempts was [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58208369/13374074) but I could not get it to work...

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I did as well get myself in the same problem as you, after looking up in the mysql2 types files, I found you can pass the result type of the query.

For example:

```
connection.query<OkPacket>('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'},
function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.insertId);
});
```

For inserts and updates you can be using the `OkPacket` type and for selects you can use `RowDataPacket`. You can type it even further by implementing `RowDataPacket` to the expected responsey type of the query and passing it in the query function.

For example:

```
export interface Post {
  title: string;
}

export interface PostRow extends RowDataPacket, Post {}
```

Then when you are querying you can pass as follows:

```
connection.query<PostRow[]>('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = 1',
function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // ...
});
```

Here it is my 2 cents, hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to solve my own problem after tackling it for a while.

It turns out, I was doing my checks incorrectly.

Before calling `auth.insertId`, you'll want to include the following check:

```js
if (!auth || !("insertId" in auth)) {
  // Do something
}
```

That way, you don't actually have to type anything, because it can get super complicated when you are attempting to do that with mysql.